# Why is DGLM in R not Recognizing my Objects?

Tags: r

I am trying to run the double generalized linear model (DGLM) in R on my traits of interest. I have made a function that extracts the components of interest from dglm with the arguments accepting a column (cT) of my Phenotypic object (Phenos), the snp (i) from my genotypic object (Geno), and PCA's (covar) to control with population structure.

```
my.pdglm <- function(cT=NULL, i=NULL, Phenos=NULL, Geno=NULL, covar=NULL)
```

The body of my p.dglm function is this as follows

```
   my.pdglm <- function(cT=NULL, i=NULL, Phenos=NULL, Geno=NULL, covar=NULL) {
          y <- Phenos[,cT]
          model <- dglm(y ~ Geno[, i] + covar[, 2] + covar[, 3] + covar[, 4] + covar[, 5] + covar[,6] + covar[,7] + covar[, 8], ~ Geno[, i], family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
          P.mean <- summary(model)$coef[2, 4]  # Extarct p values for mean part
          P.disp <- pchisq(q = anova(model)$Adj.Chisq[2], df = anova(model)$DF[2], lower.tail = FALSE)
          s.model <- summary(model$dispersion.fit)
          beta <- s.model$coef[2, 1]  # Extarct cofficients
          se <- s.model$coef[2, 2]  # Extract standard errors
          out <- data.frame(Beta = beta, SE = se, P.mean = P.mean, P.disp = P.disp, 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  # Save all the extracted 
          return(out)
}
```

When I try and run this function, I keep getting the following error using this as an example:

```
my.pdglm(cT=3, i=9173, Phenos=SP_Zm_NULL, Geno=t(Geno), covar=Zm_covar_FULL)
[1] "--------- Fitting DGLM model for SNP 9173 out of 41611  ----------"
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found
Called from: eval(predvars, data, env)
```

When I print(y) as a quality control step, it usually prints, but dglm is not recognizing it. The only way I get my function to work is if I run my function with the exact arguments named as the arguments themselves. Can anyone help me with this? This has been holding me up for a while.

Comment: Can you make this a reproducible example by including the data you're using in the function?

Comment: Yes, I can do that